# Add UserControl dynamically from file (UWP/WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, uwp

I have a `UWP` project for my raspberry pi and I want to code something like a Plugin-Loader. I already got to work, that my program imports the `.xaml` files from a directory and converts them to a `UserControl` and display them in a grid.

But those `.xaml` files don't contain the code to execute command. So I want to know if somebody got an idea to get this to work? That I can import them files with the `.cs` code.

Normally it would be done by adding the `"Class"` tag to the `.xaml` file, but it doesn't work and I get an error.

So does someone have an idea and can help me please ?

Comment: Use a class library?

Comment: What do you mean? I imported the XAML like this: `UserControl plugin = (UserControl)XamlReader.Load(xmlfile_content);` So I got the Xaml UI in my UWP Form but not the Code. So if I have a Button in my plugin xaml it doesn't do anything, because he dont have the c# code for it

Comment: Don't load the XAML, load the Control. When you build a class library (compile the controls) you can simply use the class. If you want to do that dynamically (you mentioned a Plugin-Loader) you have to use Reflection to get the Type and run that through Activator or invoke the contructor via Reflection aswell.

Comment: Sry ich les grad, dass du Deutsch kannst.. Es geht darum, ich hab die Files nicht im VS-Projekt sondern einfach in einem Ordner irgendwo am Pc. Einen Plugin-Ordner halt. Mit Windows-Forms ist das kein Problem aber in UWP gibt es viele Klassen nicht und da kenn ich mich zu wenig aus

Comment: Schon klar, das ist aber trotzdem kein Problem. Wenn du deine Controls in eine Class-Library packst (dll), kannst du die DLL in den Plugin-Ordner kopieren und per Reflection laden. den Type muss die per Name oder besser noch abhängig von implementierten Interfaces suchen und instanzieren. [Hier ein Beispiel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535602/c-sharp-plugin-reflection)

Comment: Das Funktioniert in WPF/UWP eben leider nicht, da die Klasse Assembly generell schon exisitiert aber die Methode 'LoadFile' nicht. Und das ist bei vielen Klassen so

Comment: Hmm ... tatsächlich, schade.